# Shiro with Spring MVC Wildcard permissions not working

Tags: spring-mvc, shiro

I have couple of permissions as:

```
inventory:po:view
inventory:po:create
inventory:po:update
```

In the JSP, below works:

```
<shiro:hasPermission name="inventory:po:create">
   <li><a href='<c:url value="/inventory/document/viewDocument?doctype=2" />'>Purchase Order</a></li>                   
</shiro:hasPermission>
```

However, below doesn't.

```
<shiro:hasPermission name="inventory:po:*">
</shiro:hasPermission>
```

Shiro Version is 1.2.1. I also tried using the subject.isPermitted() call in and that doesn't work too.

I'm sure this is supposed to be pretty straight forward, but is there anything I miss in the configuration to enable wildcard support ? Please advice.

**Shiro Configuration:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Security Manager -->
<bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">
    <property name="realm" ref="jdbcRealm" />
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager"/>
</bean>

<!-- Caching -->
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehCacheManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="ehCacheManager"
    class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" />

<bean id="sessionDAO"
    class="org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO" />

<bean id="sessionManager"
    class="org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager">
    <property name="sessionDAO" ref="sessionDAO" />
</bean>


<!-- JDBC Realm Settings -->
<bean id="jdbcRealm" class="org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm">
    <property name="name" value="jdbcRealm" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="authenticationQuery"
        value="SELECT password FROM system_user_accounts WHERE username=? and status=10" />
    <property name="userRolesQuery"
        value="SELECT role_code FROM system_roles r, system_user_accounts u, system_user_roles ur WHERE u.user_id=ur.user_id AND r.role_id=ur.role_id AND u.username=?" />
    <property name="permissionsQuery"
        value="SELECT code FROM system_roles r, system_permissions p, system_role_permission rp WHERE r.role_id=rp.role_id AND p.permission_id=rp.permission_id AND r.role_code=?" />



    <property name="permissionsLookupEnabled" value="true"></property>
    <property name="cachingEnabled" value="true" />
</bean>

<!-- Spring Integration -->
<bean id="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.LifecycleBeanPostProcessor" />

<!-- Enable Shiro Annotations for Spring-configured beans. Only run after 
    the lifecycleBeanProcessor has run: -->
<bean id="annotationProxy"
    class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator"
    depends-on="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor" />
<bean id="authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor"
    class="org.apache.shiro.sprinemphasized textg.security.interceptor.AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager" />
</bean>

<!-- Secure Spring remoting: Ensure any Spring Remoting method invocations 
    can be associated with a Subject for security checks. -->
<bean id="secureRemoteInvocationExecutor"
    class="org.apache.shiro.spring.remoting.SecureRemoteInvocationExecutor">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager" />
</bean>

<!-- Passthrough for Login page -->
<bean id="passThruLogin" class="org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.PassThruAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="loginUrl" value="/login" />
</bean>

<!-- Shiro filter -->
<bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager" />
    <property name="loginUrl" value="/login" />
    <property name="successUrl" value="/dashboard" />
    <property name="unauthorizedUrl" value="/error" />
    <property name="filters">
        <map>
            <entry key="authc" value-ref="passThruLogin" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
        <value> 
            <!-- !!! Order matters !!! -->
            /authenticate = anon
            /login = anon
            /logout = anon
            /error = anon
            /static/** = anon
            /** = authc
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

The " *** " isn't a wildcard in shiro's permission **checking**, on the contrary it means "requires all values". 
You should assert a wildcard right of your own (read is usually a good default wildcard permission) and be explicit on the permission check.

On the contrary '*' means '**GRANT** the user all rights', which got you confused with imho.

From *Check Permissions* part of [shiro's documentation about permission](http://shiro.apache.org/permissions.html)

> `if ( SecurityUtils.getSubject().isPermitted("printer:print") ) {
>       //print the document
>   }`
>
> Therefore, this is an incorrect check. What if the current user does not have the ability to print to any printer, but they do have the ability to print to say, the lp7200 and epsoncolor printers. Then the 2nd example above would never allow them to print to the lp7200 printer even though they have been granted that ability!